# No data being restored from iTunes backup

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore

So, I was having some unrelated problems with my iPhone, so I thought factory resetting it might fix it. The bug was fixed, but my problem came when I tried to restore my apps and data from the iTunes backup I had made. I plugged in the phone, typed in the password, and started restoring from the backup. It finished restoring, but when I turned it on it still had the cursive hello welcome screen. I thought it was normal, and kept going through the process. For some reason, while I was setting it up, it asked me if I wanted to restore from a backup. I had already restored it from my iTunes backup that I had made, so I restored again from the backup. I selected restore from Mac or PC, and I started restoring it once again. It did the same thing as before, asking me halfway through setup if I wanted to restore from a backup. I decided to press setup as new iPhone, and it didn’t transfer anything besides the things in my iCloud backup, which wasn’t much, as I only have 5 gb of iCloud storage. If it has to do with anything, I did the backup using windows 10 and I downloaded iTunes from the Microsoft store. I didn’t have enough disk space on my main drive, so I created a junction so it would save the backup files to my external Samsung SSD. When I went to restore from the backup, I decided to free up some space so I could transfer the backup to restore it using iTunes. I still have the backup files on my external drive.

Would there be any way to restore the contents of my backup? Or is my data lost forever?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t read quite right your post. BTW : when you restored your iPhone , where were you asked to restore again : on iPhone or PC : it is because, while the iPhone is not unlocked, iTunes can not see its contents. If I remember, you need to go through some step on iPhone after restore before it can be used with iTunes.

Comment: what do you mean by unlocked? i signed out of all my accounts and removed my passwords beforehand, the only other “lock” would be my sim card, as my phone is locked to verizon, but i don’t think that’s relevant

Comment: and it asked me if i wanted to restore on the phone and the phone was plugged in to the conputer

Comment: Unlocked : you entered your code on your iPhone.

Comment: When restoring iPhone you do not need to remove your iPhone from all your accounts.

Comment: do you mean the code when you connect your phone to a computer?

Comment: The code when you start your iPhone or when touchId /FaceId is not ok.

Comment: then yes i inserted the code when the phone asked me if i wanted to trust the computer also sorry for responding late

Comment: No problem.
Simple question : did you tried to connect with different lightning cable ? Or using different USB port ?

Comment: no but i’ll try that would tat have any different because i used that same cable to restore data from my old phone when i got my iphone se

Comment: i did and it didnt work